# Can we fade out Launch image xib in ios

Tags: ios, swift, launchimage

I am new in ios I have found many example of fading out of launch image but it is customised image but not launch image placed in image xcassets. So is there any solution to fade out launch image placed inside image xcassets.Please help me to resolve.Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest that you use the Launch Image, and on the next screen you put also the same image, and apply the fading effect on it, since the "Launch part" isn't manage by you, but by the OS.

Comment: But in that case next screen image should be different for different device so i need to check for it? and after launch screen goes and this image appears it wont look bad because user experience will not become bad?